# Why is Instance level methods are still accessible?

Tags: java, oop, object

## Just Curious With Confusion

I am  little bit curious about how it is happening ?
The getters and setters are instance level methods and are not in memory until unless the object creation is complete.

Here in  the code snippet i am using setters to initialize object states ,
how the constructor getting reference to the object on which the setters is to be applied ?
The main confusion is what is the exact point of object creation completion ?

```
public class Solution {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private float weight;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public float getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(float weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    Solution() {
        setName("Sachin");
        setAge(21);
        setWeight(76);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution objectReference = new Solution();
        System.out.println(objectReference);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name= " + name + "\n age= " + age + "\n weight= " + weight;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

*The getters and setters are instance level methods and are not in memory until unless the object creation is complete.* - Who told you this?. Methods are loaded when the class gets loaded. So, `setX` and `getX` methods will already be available in method-area of JVM when your construction (of the instance) is happening.

You can test this by getting the `class` of `Solution` before creating any instance and then getting all its methods via *reflection* and invoking them (you will probably get an exception, but you can invoke them :P)

Comment: so what comes first in existence the method on the mem or the state of an object ?

Comment: @shaun - Yes. Object creation is different from class loading. Methods are loaded as part of the class loading mechanism. All methods have to be loaded before they are used

Comment: got it  ,,,, thnx  @vinod

Answer (score 0):

A method consists of Java byte code. It's the same for each instance of the class. There's no need to create a separate copy of the byte code for each object. No memory needs to be allocated for the code of methods when you create a new object. An object on the heap consists of a block of memory that's large enough to contain the object's non-static member variables (plus some stuff that the JVM needs to keep track of the object).

For local variables that are used in a method, the stack is used at the moment you call the method.